# Angular UI Datepicker json set date not working

Tags: angularjs, momentjs, angular-ui, angular-moment, angular-daterangepicker

I have an angular-ui datepicker, but when I load the date remotely from the json, the datepicker doesn't select the date, but when I type it it does select the date. But it doesn't show in the input its a blank input, and when I click to open the datepicker the correct date is selected.

I would like to have the date loaded in remotely and shown in the datepicker and input field of the datepicker.

This is my code for the datepicker:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup ng-model="dt" ng-click="open()" ng-change="testFun(dt)" is-open="popup.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
<span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
</span>
```

Code to set the date:

```
$scope.today = function() {
    $scope.dt = moment($scope.tenderDate, "YYYY-MM-DD").format();
};
$scope.today();
```

$scope.tenderDate is the following:

$scope.tenderDate = $scope.data.items.Date;

Which is this in the json

```
{
    "Date":"2017-08-02"
}
```

The $scope.tenderDate works and outputs this date correctly. That is why I find it weird that when I type it in like this it selects the date in the date picker but not in the inputfield.

```
$scope.today = function() {
    $scope.dt = moment("2017-08-02", "YYYY-MM-DD").format();
};
$scope.today();
```

And without the use of momentjs and write it like this it all works. And shows the correct date "2017-08-02" like that.

```
$scope.today = function() {
    $scope.dt = new Date(2017, 7, 2);
};
```

Maybe you know a good way to get the date from json in the datepicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [docs](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) You need to assign the `$scope.dt` a value as if it would be a normal Javascript Date format.

In order to achieve that you need to use [.toDate()](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-javascript-date/) instead of [.format()](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/).

Your code would look like:

```
$scope.today = function() {
    $scope.dt = moment("2017-08-02", "YYYY-MM-DD").toDate();
};
$scope.today();
```